# Issue updating GeForce 310M on Asus K52jc

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, hdmi, nvidia-geforce

This is the first time I am having an issue installing an update to the NVIDIA 310M driver on my Asus K52JC laptop. It threw an error that it failed to install the driver. I have ran the suggested solution of downloading & running DDU, then running the driver update going through custom and performing a clean installation. That did not work, as I still got the issue. I can install it manually through the device manager, but I want to avoid that if at all possible. The way I had it setup was that I was using my TV via the HDMI port. Unless that caused an issue, I'm not sure as to why it is doing this. The bios is at the latest version. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I read your post and remembered back to the problems I had trying to update my older ASUS ul80vt laptop (with a NVIDIA® GeForce® G 210M, Windows 7 SP1).  I learned the hard way, that ASUS sometimes uses hybrid graphics cards that require drivers **directly** from them (ASUS).  Using other drivers will not work.  It appears you may be faced with the same dilemma as evidenced by [this post](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/480104/geforce-mobile-gpus/why-official-latest-drivers-do-not-support-asus-k52jc/1/) on the GeForce.com forums.  You should first verify that you are using a hybrid driver.  And, if you are, go to the ASUS web site/forums for any updates.